# Want to change an img src on hover, then to a different src on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, hover, click

I have a div which contains an img - I want to be able to have the img src change on hover (and then back again when not hovered), but also have the same img change to a different src altogether when it is clicked (and then back again upon second click). So far I have the J-Query code to make it change on hover:

HTML

```
<div class="tab_box">
   <img id="img1" src="tab.png">
</div>
```

J-QUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){$('#img1').hover(function(){$(this).attr('src','tabt2.png')},function()
{$(this).attr('src','tab.png')}) });
```

But I am unsure how to then make the  change to a different src altogether if clicked (as the image will have to be being hovered over to click it!) Can anyone suggest? For various re-sizing reasons, I want to keep the image as a stand alone image within the div, instead of having it as a background-image of the div, if possible

Comment: just use `.on('hover', function()` and `.on('click', function()` , and simply do `$('#img1').off()` or `$('#img1').off('hover')` once the image is clicked on

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - are you able to provide a js-fiddle to show what you mean in action please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .hover() and .click() functions of Jquery. What you have used has syntax problems

Here is the correct code:

```
$('#img1').hover(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://www.fateheducation.com/fatehnew/Testimonial_Image/avatar-small.png');
});
$('#img1').click(function () {
    $(this).attr('src', 'http://moduleoff.com/sites/all/themes/moduleoff/images/xdruplicon_rotated_small.png.pagespeed.ic.Xl8nCuL4lR.png')
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awttt8uz/)